# How to fade in element after scrolled to

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, sticky

I'm using a scroll to script which changes the display of the element from none to block when a certain point is reached on the page.

Is there any way of applying a fade in as well as changing the display, or even load an animated gif?

Here is my code

```
window.onscroll = function()
{
if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 454 || self.pageYOffset > 454) {
    $('logosmall').style.position = 'fixed';
    $('logosmall').style.top = '0';
    $('logosmall').style.padding = '10px';
    $('logosmall').style.display = 'block';
} else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 454 || self.pageYOffset < 454) {
        $('logosmall').style.position = 'absolute';
        $('logosmall').style.top = '454px';
        $('logosmall').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply chain [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) or [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). When doing so, it's always a good idea to use [`.stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) so you don't queue animations. I've also re-factored your code to be more efficient with respect to the styling:

```
window.onscroll = function() {

    if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 454 || self.pageYOffset > 454) {

            $('logosmall').css({

                'position' : 'fixed',
                'top'      : '0',
                'padding'  : '10px'

            }).stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');

        } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 454 || self.pageYOffset < 454) {

            $('logosmall').css({

                'position' : 'absolute',
                'top'      : '454px'

            }).stop(true, true).fadeOut(0);

        }
    }
}
```

P.S.  I'm not sure if it's a typo or not, but is logosmall a class or an id? If it's a class, you need to preface it with a period: `.logosmall`.  If it's an id, you need to preface it with a pound sign: `#logosmall`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using this code as well as a scroll to anchor but they don't seem to work together, tried putting a jquery no conflict but didn't work...

Comment: Have you checked in the console log for any issues?  Put some logging to see where it's stopping.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing

```
$('logosmall').style.display = 'block';
```

to

```
$('logosmall').fadeIn();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really understand what you need. But if you just want to make a fadeIn, the solution is here http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

```
$('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
```